# Was Cloud and Tifa living together and raising kids in Advent Children?

Tags: final-fantasy

In *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children*, was Cloud and Tifa living together and raising kids?

We can clearly see that Tifa seeing a room (looks like Cloud's room) when she was trying to pick up the phone ringing (at first minute of the movie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Wikia they do live together

> Concerned with this new development, Rufus attempts to make contact with the now retired members of AVALANCHE, specifically with **Cloud Strife, who now lives in the newly built city of Edge with another AVALANCHE member, Tifa Lockhart**, and two children, Marlene Wallace and Denzel, who is infected with Geostigma.

Source: [Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children > Story](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII:_Advent_Children#Story)

as you can see Rufus was trying to reach Cloud when he called Tifa.

as for the kids. they aren't their own if that's what you are wondering. they are

- Marlene Wallace: the daughter of Barret's friends Dyne and Eleanor who Barret adopted after Corel was burned down by Shina. Tifa has been looking after her since before *Advent Children* as Marlene was shown in 7th Heaven in Midgar Sector 7 Slums
- Denzel: a boy who used to live on the Sector 7 Plate before Shinra blew up the pillar. after the game but before the movie Denzel found Cloud's bike and called the last number on his phone which was the number to 7th Heaven in Edge before succumbing to his Geostigma only for Cloud to find him. Tifa and Cloud take him in as they felt responsible for Sector 7's destruction (as they couldn't stop it)
- (After the film)

  > Shelke Rui: former member of Deepground who after helping Vincent fight Omega, started living out the 10 years she lost while in Deepground with Tifa and Cloud

  ^ added that because i did hear they make an appearance at the end of *Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children Complete*

Answer (score 0):

Up until the start of Advent Children Cloud and Tifa have actually been living together.